# PHP if/else without echo

Tags: php, echo

How do I replace `echo` with proper html codes? Since there will be hundreds of html codes, using echo doesn't make sense.

```
<?php
if ($this->item->catid == 9) { 
    echo "yes, it exists"; 
    } 
    else { 
    echo "no, it don't exist"; 
    }
?>
```

I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean, how can one cleanly output many lines of HTML conditionally without having to `echo` each individual line?

If that's the case, something like this would do the trick:

```
<?php
if ($this->item->catid == 9) { 
?>

    <!--- put all the raw output you like here --->

<?php
} else { 
?>

    <!--- put all the raw output you like here --->

<?php
}
?>
```

The "raw output" would be anything sent to the browser.  HTML, JavaScript, etc.  Even though it's outside of the server-side PHP tags, as far as the PHP processor is concerned it's still between the `{ ... }` brackets.  So it's only output as part of that conditional block.

Answer (score 1):

There is two way to do it :

1) As suggested by David, by closing your `php` tags to write raw HTML.

```
<?php
if ($this->item->catid == 9) { 
?>
    // HTML goes here
<?php
}else{
?>
    // HTML goes here
<?php
}
?>
```

But if you're planning to write a lot of text it might be a be hard to read your code in the end so you can use the following.

```
<?php

$htmlOutput = '';

if ($this->item->catid == 9) { 
    $htmlOutput .=  "yes, it exists";
} else { 
    $htmlOutput .=  "no, it doesn't exist";
}
?>
```

You create a variable that will contain all your HTML by appending a part of it everytime you need to so in the end you'll only need to print a single variable.